# Release management with TFS and SSIS

Tags: sql-server, ssis, business-intelligence, release-management

We currently work with `SSIS` Packages 2012 together with `TFS`.

Our big challenge at the moment is to setup a feasible deployment process due to lacking capabilities when merging packages (xml, compiled code etc).

Any one out there working with such tools can point me to an approach that we can use ?

Comment: I fear this is off topic (shopping) but it is a damn interesting question. Add to that that SSIS is VS 2010 (whoever decided SQL VIsual Studio is one generation behind). One of the big "not totally ok" things in the development story, sadly. I hope you get a good answer. I could need it, too.

Answer (score 2):

Release management is important, and gaining importance every day. In the past I have approached a solution by combining business practices and software development practices. I have found developing small, unit-of-work SSIS packages helps - especially in enterprises where a team is responsible for developing  data integration solutions. This has the advantages of simplifying troubleshooting and maintenance, while promoting code re-use (which improves quality and reduces development time).

The downside to developing smaller SSIS packages is finding a good way to execute them. In SSIS 2012, you can utilize the SSIS Catalog, which is a pretty cool SSIS Framework. There are other frameworks available on the market, and you can also build your own. Currently, I build SSIS 2012 Frameworks that leverage SSIS Catalog functionality where appropriate and extend the catalog where needed.

Hope this helps,
Andy